# MvvmCross SQLite plugin in Windows Phone 8

Tags: sqlite, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross

I'm creating a cross-platform application (Android, iOS, WP8) which using multiple SQLite databases. I installed MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.Sqlite on all platforms, but it is not working on WP8. I'm getting this exception:

```
"Could not open database file: C:\\Data\\Users\\DefApps\\AppData\\{284E2D10-051E-48D8-B895 E8126CCE3192}\\Local\\database.sqlite (CannotOpen)".
```

I'm opening the database like this:

```
dataService.Initialize(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, filename));
```

Then I tried to swith to the new Sqlite plugin (MvvmCross - Community SQLite-Net Plugin), and it giving me strange errors on almost every query:

```
        Message:    "not an error"
        StackTrace: "   at Community.SQLite.SQLite3.Prepare2(sqlite3 db, String query)\r\n   at Community.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.Prepare()\r\n   at Community.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.<ExecuteDeferredQuery>d__0`1.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at Community.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.ExecuteQuery[T]()\r\n   at Community.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.Query[T](String query, Object[] args)\r\n   at
```

Any suggestions how can I make it work?

**EDIT:**

I found out that the reason behind "not an error" was my multi-threading. I used Task.Run and await to create background thread (which worked fine on iOS and Android, but it failed on WP8). I removed that from my code (with #if WINDOWS_PHONE directives) so right now it's working synchronously. But the Community SQLite plugin can't map my SQLite Date type to DateTime. It always gives me the same DateTime: {0001.01.01. 0:00:00}.

Btw how can I use native SQLite? Can you show me a sample? I need to add new SQLite lib to my WP8 project, and implement IDataService, ISQLiteConnectionFactory, and register them on:

```
Setup.InitializeLastChance()
{
     Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IDataService, MyOwnDataService>();
     Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ISQLiteConnectionFactory , MyOwnConnectionFactory>();
}
```

Comment: Do the samples - such as N=10 in http://mvvmcross.blogspot.co.uk work for your setup? For wp8, I know a number of people are moving to the native (C++) sqlite assemblies for wp8, but the community C# sqlite port *should* still be working.

Comment: @Stuart Yes, I did the same thing as you in N=10. I edited my answer with more details.